# function continuous depending on the parameter

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Find $a,c$ such that:

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} a\frac{\exp(tgx)}{(1+\exp(tgx))} &\text{for }|x|<\pi/2  \\[2ex] \exp(cx)-2 &\text{for }  |x|\ge\pi/2 \end{cases}$$

is continuous.

How do I evaluate the left- and right-hand limits to see if they are equal?

Comment: exp(tgx) is equal to $e^(tanx)$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ \lim_{x\to(\frac\pi2)^-}\frac{a\exp\tan x}{1+\exp\tan x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{a\exp x}{1+\exp x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{a x}{1+ x}=a.$$

Comment: ok then $exp(c*(\frac{\pi}{2}))-2=a \implies c=\frac{2ln(2+a)}{\pi}$ But have either $ lim_{x\to-\pi/2}$

Answer (score 0):

To prove the function is continuous, you need to fullfill the condition

$$ \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0). $$

So, as a first step, you need to prove that the limit exists at the point $x_0$, that is why you need to prove
$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2^{-}}f(x)= \lim_{x\to \pi/2^{+}}f(x).$$